# Scaling problems with 4K / UHD / Retina / 3840x2160 screen

Tags: laptop, monitors, windows, uhd

I'm about to buy a laptop, and have  narrowed it down to either a model with hd or uhd (3840x2160) screen.  I like the image quality of the uhd, but I'm seeing a lot of complaints about scaling problems on review sites.

Is it too early to go uhd, and should I wait until mainstream business applications catch up?

Comment: UHD causes a lot of problems, but most scaling issues can be fixed in some way. It's not a massive setback in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in modern stuff, you won't have a problem. Scaling issues only occur with dated software. So, as long as you aren't trying to run Battlefield 1942 you should be able to enjoy your UHD display. Media content has also been getting better suited for 4k, so it is definitely not to early to make the upgrade.